# Red-Pitaya Kernel: add additional Modules

Tags: redpitaya

Is it possible to add additional modules for some USB devices to the default redPitaya kernel?

Right now the kernel seems to be static without module support.

Especially focus on adding several usb-WIFI dongles to make them work out of the box - the only USB WIFI driver that I have found to be compiled in is: 8192cu.

It may also be helpful adding some other modules like USB-serial console or such...

(also enabling /proc/config.gz may help...)

Answer (score 4):

In release 0.90, the Red Pitaya kernel is static with only 8192cu WiFi support in order to minimize the size of the kernel & especially the ramdisk.

But, like any other Linux kernel, it is configurable. You can build your own kernel flavour by modifying the [Red Pitaya kernel configuration file](https://github.com/RedPitaya/RedPitaya/blob/master/OS/linux/config/rp_defconfig) and rebuilding the kernel & modules. But keep in mind the ramdisk size is limited to 10 MB due to current u-boot configuration. The elegant solution would therefore be to put the modules onto the SD card (/opt/lib) instead of increasing the ramdisk.

Regarding /proc/config.gz, it is already enabled in release 0.90 and can be accessed using:

```
redpitaya> gunzip -dc /proc/config.gz
```